# how to dynamically add values in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
{Doctor.day1 && Doctor.**day1**.map((row) => (
<Link className="timing" to={''}>
 <span>{row.start}</span> <span>AM</span>
  </Link>
))}
```

how can I dynamically add the value of `day1` to the above code,here doctor is a state variable and day1 is the array inside doctor state.

Comment: Doctor.day1.map(), just access it like you access any properties on an object

Comment: You can use bracket notation to access a property by the string value of its name: `Doctor['day1'].map(/*...*/)`